# How to share existing main app source code with ShareExtension iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

I am working on building a ShareExtension for my app. I have replaced custom view[SLComposeServiceViewController] with main app's ViewController.

Well in this scenario, I have to set target of main ViewController with the share extension. The problem I faced doing this is, my main app's view controller is heavy and has lot of code inside it. I am getting many build time errors and I am solving it manually by adding all the dependency class target to my share extension.

My question here is, Is there any better way to do this? Is there any better way to share all the code with extension by adding entire main app code to extension target ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to keep seperate UI and class for share extension . As Apple suggest Extensions should be kept light weight .

Comment: Thanks, But the problem in my case is it would be very difficult to move all the codes manually and handle all scenarios. I am looking for any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: so what you need is all the code from main app should be available to extension tooo right ?  in that case tick the extension target for all the files in main app

Comment: Yes I did that aswell. I faced a problem in instantiating appdelegate inside share application. Infact lot of code blocks in main app has app delegate instance. I am getting build time errors while setting the target to extension. How do I tackle that ?